# How to start a Dialog Fragment on click of a recyler view item which is inside a fragment itself?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Let me first explain you the design.

I have Activity A, which has a Fragment inside it which in turn has a recylerview. Now I want to open a dialog fragment on click of recylerview's item.

I am setting click listener for view in ViewHolder (implements OnClickListerner)

Question 1. Should I directly open the Dialog Fragment from viewholder's onCLick method OR should I first propagate the click from ViewHolder to ACtivity and activity will then start the Dialog fragment.

Comment: `directly open the Dialog Fragment from viewholder's onCLick method`

Comment: but dont they say that all the navigations should be done from parent activity and not with in fragments

Comment: `they say that all the navigations should be done from parent activity` as i think you are showing  `DialogFragment ` instead of starting new screen so you can start it from viewholder's onCLick method  without propagate the click event to Activity

Comment: that makes total sense, thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK how do I get getSupportFragmentManager() in ViewHolder's onCLick method ???

Comment: pass FragmentManager object to class in which you are using `ViewHolder`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89547/discussion-between-t-c-and--k).

Comment: Problem solved or not?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yup that worked, thanks, one last follow up question, when I show the Dialog fragment on click I need to first fetch data and then show downloaded data in this Dialog fragment, but since I showing the DialogFragment before fetching data I am not able to update the message. How do I do this?